# MySql Php вывод запроса php

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с двумя столбцами,первый столбец имя, второй сумма. Как мне посчитать всю сумму и вывести ее на экран в html.

Как сделать запрос знаю, не врубаю как вывести все это на php 
Запрос такой

```
SELECT SUM(  `sum` ) 
FROM actualparish
```

Answer (score 3):

Используй PDO.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT SUM(  sum ) FROM actualparish') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Пример из документации.